# Calling an API based on data within cells A2:A100 and outputting to cells G2:G100

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've been trying to figure out how to get a Google AppsScript to pull in an API for keyword rank tracking directly within Google Sheets.

The loop is required to dynamically pull in information from column A and output the keyword ranking position into column G.

The keywords are in cells A2-A100. The ranking position (which is the only thing we are pulling from the API) we are popping into the corresponding row in column G, starting from G2. For testing purposes, we've got the loop set from 1 to 3.

We're at a bit of a loss as to why this isn't working as expected, and would really appreciate a nudge in the right direction!

The issue is that the very first result always returns 'keyword = undefined' within the API, and returning a result of '-1', meaning that the first row is not read. We've tried updating the r to 0, to 2, and changing the r references to no avail.

This makes us think that there must be something wrong with the loop, rather than the rest of the code, but please do correct me if this is not the case.

The script we've gotten so far is;

```
function callAPI() {
  //New loop
  for (r = 1; r <= 3; r++) {
    {
      //Find keyword, encode query and url
      var query = keyword;
      var url =
        'https://api.avesapi.com/search?apikey={{APIKEYREMOVEDFORPRIVACY}}&type=web&' +
        'google_domain=google.co.uk&gl=gb&hl=en&device=mobile&output=json&num=100&tracked_domain={{CLIENTDOMAIN}}.com&position_only=true&uule2=London,%20United%20Kingdom' +
        '&query=' +
        encodeURIComponent(query);

      //Call API and add to log
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true });
      Logger.log(response);

      //Get column value for keyword
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var keyword = sheet.getRange(1 + r, 1).getValue();
    }

    //Set value of column
    var results = sheet.getRange(1 + r, 7).setValue(response);
  }
}
```

Additional edit:
So this is crystal clear, the desired input is;

- keyword in A2 is read using the API and the output found (ranking position) is fed into G2.
- the loop should then read A3, find the corresponding ranking position within the API, and adds that value to G3
- rinse and repeat until the end of the loop.

Hopefully this is enough to go on, would really appreciate any advice, thank you!

Comment: Sorry - that should read 'why this isn't working' - I think you caught me before I edited that one to read properly!

Comment: You  access the `keyword` before the `keyword` gets it's value from spreadsheet.

Comment: All this time I thought the ordering didn't matter within a function and have been scratching my head, thanks for taking a look TheMaster, really appreciate it!

Comment: You might also want to take a look at "Best practices" in the [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info), if you're going to be  calling setValue 100 times.

Comment: thanks TheMaster, would you suggest using an array to speed it up then?

Comment: Yes, I would````.````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically from TheMaster's comments you switch up your statements to this:

```
function callAPI() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var keywords = sheet.getRange(2,1,3).getValues();
  var responses = [];
  //New loop
  for (r = 0; r <= 2; r++) {
      //Find keyword, encode query and url
      var query = keywords[r][0];
      var url =
        'https://api.avesapi.com/search?apikey={{APIKEYREMOVEDFORPRIVACY}}&type=web&' +
        'google_domain=google.co.uk&gl=gb&hl=en&device=mobile&output=json&num=100&tracked_domain={{CLIENTDOMAIN}}.com&position_only=true&uule2=London,%20United%20Kingdom' +
        '&query=' +
        encodeURIComponent(query);

      //Call API and add to log
      var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true });
      Logger.log(resp);
      responses.push([resp]);
  }
    //Set value of column
  sheet.getRange(2,7,3).setValues(responses);
}
```

Note that I moved the sheet declaration outside the loop, it needs to be only called once.

**EDIT:** I updated the code to follow best practices in the tag info page. Note the usage of arrays as return values of `getValues()` and parameter of `setValues()`.